# Setting center and resolution on initialization of view results in center going to [NaN, NaN] on zooming with mouse

Tags: openlayers

I'm using the following to initialize my view for the map in openlayers 4.

```
var olview = new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat(coords),
    resolution: resolution,
    minResolution: 0.025,
    maxResolution: 2500,
    projection: 'EPSG:3857'
});
```

The coords and resolution are passed as arguments to the function that creates the view. When zooming with the mouse the center of the map goes to [NaN, NaN]. Using the or the plus/minus buttons or animate function on the view works as expected, and after animating the view the zoom functionality works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause was that the resolution was being passed as a string. Openlayers doesn't check types or convert them, so passing types that aren't the expected type in the documentation can cause things to break ([here's an issue](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/6016) discussing it). Setting resolution to `parseFloat(resolution)` fixed the problem.